# Include modules from node_modules in the bundle

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm a bit noob with VSC. I'm compiling/transpiling TypeScript code using "ES2015" and "system" to create a single JS file bundle.
In this project I'm using ThreeJS library (JS modules) installed in node_modules.

Everything works fine and compiles with no errors, except ThreeJS modules are not included in the bundle file. Only my code (from .ts files) is transpiled.

I've tried changing the modules import in many ways, from importing the whole library:

```
  import THREE from "node_modules/three";
```

to import only the parts I need:

```
  import { Vector3 } from "three";
```

but it doesn't work.

The library has both the modules and the definition files in "node_modules". Maybe I'm doing something wrong or maybe it is intended to work like that.
Is there a way to include the modules from node_modules in the bundle?

Main reasons:
- Easier to mantain. I only need to update a single ThreeJS library.
- Library files will be included in the generated source map.
- I'm trying to avoid learning about ("fighting with") extra programs like WebPack.

This is my latest tsconfig.json file (using TypeScript 3.7.2):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "watch": true,
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "system",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "./debug/js/bundle.js",
    "outDir": "./debug/js",    
    "strict": true,                  
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "rootDirs": [
      "./src",
      "../node_modules/three/build"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "node_modules": ["node_modules"],
      "three": ["node_modules/three/src/Three"]
    },
    "removeComments": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "incremental": true,
    "pretty": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "../debug",
    "../build",
    "../node_modules/tslint"
  ]
}
```